# Авторизация при проксировании nginx

Tags: nginx

подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать авторизацию при проксировании. Есть два сервера(бекенд и фронт). По требованиям безопасности необходимо чтобы было проксирование с фронта на бек по защищенному соединению с авторизацией по сертификату. В данный момент реализовано только соединение.

```
location @laravel {
    proxy_pass https://test:9000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote addr;
    proxy_ssl_verify on;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/test.cer;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/test.key;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/testca.cer;
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
    proxy ssl ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384: ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305: ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256";
}
```

Comment: Вставьте код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: @AlexeyTen поправил

Comment: Так proxy_ssl_certificate_key это вроде и есть тот самый сертификат авторизации

Comment: @AlexeyTe это сертификат не сервера бекенда

Comment: Так, ещё раз. `proxy_ssl_verify on`/`proxy_ssl_verify_depth` — включает проверку сертификата бекенда. `proxy_ssl_certificate`/`proxy_ssl_certificate_key` отправляют на бекенд сертификат клиента. Больше в этом конфиге ничего не нужно. Проверка валидности клиента происходит на сервере test:9000. Его конфиг вы нам не показали. Если там тоже nginx, то надо включить `ssl_verify_client`

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/